# Suppress echo from PHP include file

Tags: php

I have a file `PHP01.php` which: 
- performs a function
- creates an array
- echo's some message

I need to include this file in another php script, say `PHP02.php` as I need access to the array it created. But when I jquery POST request to `PHP02.php`, the data it returns also has the `echo` from `PHP01.php`

How can I suppress the echo from the first file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can output buffer it if editing or otherwise restructuring is not possible:

```
ob_start();

include "PHP02.php";

ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you should look at refactoring the code in the original PHP file.  If it's performing a function, it should do that.  Then, the code that called the function should decide if they want to echo a message.

As you've just learned, this is an important part of orthogonal design.  I'd recommend re-writing it so that it performs what you want it to, and let the code that calls the function, decide what they want to output.  That way you won't have to worry about these things again.

You can also look into using output buffers.  See `ob_flush` in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a conditional to `PHP01.php` that checks to see where it is being called from, this will ensure that you only echo it out if the file making the call is `PHP01.php`

Additionally it is better if you place functions in their own file to be included if needed so as to keep certain features that are present from being included for example in `PHP01.php` you can add `include 'function01.php';` and it will have that function shared across the two files.

Answer (score -1):

create a new function without the `echo`